# HTML/CSS: Responsive table

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-table, responsive-design

I have a table like this on my wordpress side:

```css
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.text-center-row>th,
.text-center-row>td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table style="border: none;" class="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="text-center-row">
      <td style="border: none;">Icon 1</td>
      <td style="border: none;">Icon 2</td>
      <td style="border: none;">Icon 3</td>
      <td style="border: none;">Icon 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center-row">
      <td style="border: none;">Text with Link 1</td>
      <td style="border: none;">Text with Link 2</td>
      <td style="border: none;">Text with Link 3</td>
      <td style="border: none;">Text with Link 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately this is not fitting on smaller mobile screens, so I would like to change this table to a responsive table with HTML/CSS. I have found a lot of examples in the internet, but unfortunately no one is fitting more. I want to have a table like this on a mobile view:

```
  Icon 1
Text&Link 1
  Icon 2
Text&Link 2
  Icon 3
Text&Link 3
  Icon 4
Text&Link 4
```

It is somehow required to take a column and use it as a row below.

Can somebody help with a code snippet?
Thanks and kind regards
NKL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DIVS

```css
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

#iconContainer { text-align:center;  width: 100vw; }
#iconContainer div { display:inline-block; padding: 0 5px 0 5px; }
```

```html
<div id="iconContainer">
<div class="text-center">Icon 1<br/>Text with Link 1</div>
<div class="text-center">Icon 2<br/>Text with Link 2</div>
<div class="text-center">Icon 3<br/>Text with Link 3</div>
<div class="text-center">Icon 4<br/>Text with Link 4</div>
<div class="text-center">Icon 5<br/>Text with Link 5</div>
</div>
```

Smaller screen:

[image]

Comment: Hi, in general this works as desired, thanks. Unfortunately the ```#container``` block in the CSS is modifying my complete Wordpress side and is affecting the general view of all pages. Perhaps this ```#container``` keyword is already used by my wordpress theme? Is there a possibility to use a different naming to resolve the conflict?

Comment: Sure, change it to whatever

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with a different name, this seems not to be the problem.
The problem is, that this ```div { display:inline-block }``` is overriding the normal ```div``` which is used multiple times on the page.
Is it possible to change this somehow?

Comment: Of course. Very simple. See update

Comment: Great, works like a charm now. Thanks!
There is a typo in the last ```</div>```. You are writing ```</Ddiv>```

Comment: Is it also possible to have a little bit more space between the divs?
Currently it is more or less like this:
```Text with Link 1 Text with Link 2 Text with Link 3 Text with Link 4``` and not
```Text with Link 1          Text with Link 2         Text with Link 3        Text with Link 4```

Comment: I have added padding to the divs.  That is really basic CSS.

Comment: Yes, basic CSS, sorry. I am normally not working on websites, but yeah, sometimes I need to.
This padding is also increasing the size on top and below of the div, not only between the single divs. I changed it to padding-left:5px and padding-right:5px. This is looking better now. If I increase the value further to equally distribute the icons/links on the website width, the mobile-view is looking buggy if I decrease the screen size. Is there something to equally distribute it in the window?

Comment: Yes. you can (and possibly SHOULD) use FLEX - that is not something I can help you with directly

Comment: Thanks. The "FLEX" keyword was perfect. Here are some links for it:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
https://blog.kulturbanause.de/2019/06/flexbox-responsive-layouts-ohne-media-queries/
Thanks for your help!
Unfortunately this topic has been closed already (but the reference answer-topic is not fitting to my needs), otherwise I would have shown my solution in here...

Comment: YOu can post a jsfiddle link in your question